# add a jquery datepicker into a jquery facebox overlay form... how?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, facebox

facebox form works well... but if I add datepicker nothing appear...
for example facebox open a page called form.php ...in this page if I click on a input field, datepicker doesn't appear. if i open form.php directly into the browser (without passing for the page with the link for facebox), datepicker WORKS!!!

what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your included page's html is injected into the original page, so if you didn't include datepicker references into that page it won't work.

Comment: can you help me? because i'm not very good :( i'll post my work here: http://rapidshare.com/files/379213492/datepicker_and_facebox.zip.html

index.html is the page who load facebox form
page loaded is called contact.php
in contact.php there is a field called datepicker i want to click it and appear.
only_datepicker.html is only a example downloaded from the web... if you can modify my 2 pages index.html and contact.php to work i'll appreciate very much!! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try this but keep in mind your z-index for the datepicker as it may need to be adjusted to display ontop of facebox.

[http://www.sylv3rblade.com/2009/12/using-jquery-datepicker-with-facebox/][1]

Comment: already seen... but i don't know where must i put the code :(